# Is the Idea of "Community Judging" really that fair?

Tags: support, post-ban, bad-questions

**My Bad History on Stack Overflow:**

I created a Stack Overflow account about a year ago, and I sort of missed the facts about all the rules and regulations, so I have a pretty [bad history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7589150/abdulrahman-attia) of questions. Unfortunately, this made me unable to ask any more questions.

**I Resolved To Fix It**

I answered lots of questions, many that got upvotes and were accepted. But from what I read on other posts, the most important thing to lift a question ban is to improve your questions. And that's exactly what I did.... However, since they were asked a long time ago, no one bothers to go there again and evaluate my questions again, so I received no credit for doing so.

**The New Problem**

The fact that most of my posts and answers are now helpful and contributory to the site, should most likely mean that my ban should be lifted. But no! Stack Overflow just keeps sticking that beautiful old ban all over my face.

So what do you think about this? I understand that normally, the community is great and very important in making Stack Overflow as good as it is, but sometimes old questions are just ignored even if the OP has improved it. Doesn't that count as a disadvantage to people who are trying to find solutions to similar problems as one the OP has himself?

**Does Stack overflow have a way of notifying people who took part in a question when the question is edited?**

If so, why doesn't anyone go back and change their vote or bad idea (i.e: upvote or remove downvote?)

Comment: The kinds of comments you have been posting, begging for upvotes and acceptances, tend to backfire.

Comment: Yeah I know- something I learnt here :)

Comment: Anyway, regarding the substance of your complaint: you have posted several times after being warned by the site about your post quality, and your most recent question-ban just started a couple of hours ago. It's not like the site isn't giving you lots of chances.

Comment: I've only had one. And as I said, I improved some of the questions, but I still got nothing

Comment: And no, we don't notify everyone who interacted with a question when the question is edited. That would be overwhelming for most users.

Comment: the fact that later on when i learned more about how this site works I edited my question and got 0 credit for that?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAttia Well, that is unfortunate, but that is the risk you run when asking off-topic or unspecific questions and edit them later.

Comment: So do you know how I can fix this. Stack Overflow is the only website that responds to my questions and queries, and despite the negativity, I still end up getting an answer within the range of ten minutes. It's saddenning to loose such a usefull site

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAttia As Modus said, your tone and attitude are not helping your cause. We want to help you, but people tend to be less inclined to help if you come at them with accusations and a lot of complaining. **Everything you can do to get out of a question ban is explained here: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/2057919).**

Comment: It doesn't say anything about the exact limit. Is there a specific number of votes that when you reach you get banned from asking a question?

Comment: You have enough rep to put a bounty on two questions.  If you know you did it right and edited them into shape then you can get enough upvotes to get unblocked, even earn the bounty back.  If you didn't, well, god speed.

Comment: Just create a new account and start over with a fresh scorecard and your newly obtained knowledge, I would suggest.

Comment: Fairness is subjective. Some SO users think that they shoud not be subjected to a barrage of bad questions that are totally off-topic because OP's did not read the help/tour.  Some users think that there are too many homework questions from deadbeat students who will not search SO/Google for duplicates before their assignment copypasta.  Some that they are wasting too much effort closing untested, undebugged code dumps, copied from other students or some crappy tutorial site.  There is plenty of unfairness to go round.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Isn't the Stack Overflow Community a bit UNFAIR in this matter?

tl;dr: No.

You had your chance. You have asked at least 10 questions (some may be deleted). That was 10 opportunities that you had to positively contribute to the site. And despite this, your negative contributions still weighed heavily enough that you got question banned.

Getting a question ban is *not easy*. It doesn't happen overnight. It requires *repeated* flouting of our standards. And you're notified that you're not positively impacting the site because your questions get downvoted.

We were being fair when we allowed you to keep asking questions after the first time one of your questions went into negative votes. We tolerated your behavior for several questions thereafter.

How much more should *we*, the community of productive SO users, have to tolerate from those who have clearly chosen not to be productive? At some point, once a user has clearly fallen too far, we have to wipe our hands with them.

You have reached that point.

> Does Stack overflow have a way of notifying people who took part in a question when the question is edited

No.

It is the responsibility of users to ask good questions *the first time*. Yes, we allow users to go back and edit them into shape. But that doesn't mean that it's OK to ask a bad question.

And it certainly doesn't mean that anyone who downvoted a bad question now has some *eternal* responsibility to re-evaluate that question whenever the asker edits it.

If you had done your job correctly the first time, you wouldn't need re-evaluation.

This may seem harsh, but we get *thousands* of questions a day. We cannot coddle each individual user and babysit every single question they ask.

Comment: It is a bit harsh, but I get it. Can you please tell me if there is a specific number of votes i have to reach before getting the ban lifted?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAttia: The specific nature of the question-ban system is *deliberately* kept hidden.

Comment: Note that the ban lifts after 6 months and you'll be able to ask another question. If _that_ question is poorly received, you'll be banned again.

Comment: @Tas No, that's not true at all.  The ban has no time limit at all.  It doesn't lift after 6 months.  You are allowed to as a question, if you haven't done so in 6 months, *even if you are below the threshold for the post ban*.  You do not get "banned again" if your question is bad, rather, your question needs to be *so good* that it brings you *out* of the post ban for it to actually end.  The further below the threshold you are, the better your question needs to be to bring you back.  Thus the "post ban" isn't actually a post ban, it's just a really significant post rate-limit.